# Is this layout possible in Flexbox?

Tags: flexbox

I have been trying to achieve following layout with Flexbox layout mode, but without success and now I am wondering is it even possible.

I can make layout like in picture but need to use two more containers inside main container for columns but that way I can't control position of items in a way that I want when the width of screen changes.

Link to picture: https://www.dropbox.com/s/yxuf253ywzsr831/desired_effect.png?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve the similar behavior with flex box ordering and media queries

you should change the ordering of the flex items when ever the width changes

```
/*for example*/

@media (max-width:200px) { 
    .flex4{
        order:2;
    }   
}
```

I just created two versions of the layouts but you might have to use media queries according to your requirements.

```css
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow:column wrap;
  width:300px;
  height:350px;
}

.flex-container-comp {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  -ms-box-orient: horizontal;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow:column wrap;
  width:300px;
}

.flex-item {
  background: tomato;
  border: 5px solid red;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  height:100px;
}

.flex1{
    order:1;
}

.flex2{
    order:2;
}

.flex3{
    order:3;
}

.flex4{
  height:200px;
  order:4;
}

.flex5{
  order:5;
}

.flex6{
  order:6;
}

.flex-comp1{
    order:1;
}

.flex-comp2{
    order:3;
}

.flex-comp3{
    order:4;
}

.flex-comp4{
  height:200px;
  order:2;
}

.flex-comp5{
  order:5;
}

.flex-comp6{
  order:6;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item flex1">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item flex2">2</li>
   <li class="flex-item flex3">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item flex4">4</li>
   <li class="flex-item flex5">5</li>
</ul>
<br/>
<br/>
<br/>
<ul class="flex-container-comp">
  <li class="flex-item flex-comp1">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item flex-comp2">2</li>
   <li class="flex-item flex-comp3">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item flex-comp4">4</li>
   <li class="flex-item flex-comp5">5</li>
  <li class="flex-item flex-comp6">6</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but I'm not able to achieve what I want. On following link is my example [link](https://jsbin.com/civegoj/edit?html,css,output) . As you can see my main container contain 2 columns and what I would like is to have 8 item that would behave exactly like link above except when _width < 500px_ than I would have 8 item to position them how I like.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't sure of the exact behavior you were after so I made this one pretty flexible if you wanted to have the left column of a different width than the right column when they are in the "wide screen" mode. This uses a media query to change the "order" of the divs in the flexbox. It also uses javascript to  manage the widths and heights of the elements throughout. It is difficult to play with the width of the window below, so you can play with it here instead:
https://jsfiddle.net/FrancisMacDougall/srgmpgx0/

```js
var ids = {
  flex1: { hmul:0.32 },
  flex2: { hmul:0.32 },
  flex3: { hmul:0.32 },
  flex4: { hmul:0.64 },
  flex5: { hmul:0.32 }
};
function resize() {
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  var xoff = container.offsetLeft;
  var yoff = container.offsetTop;
  var w = container.offsetWidth;
  var h = (window.innerHeight - yoff) - 8;
  var big = (window.innerWidth>500);

  document.getElementById("dimensions").innerHTML = 
    "Size: "+ window.innerWidth + " x " + window.innerHeight;

  if(big)
    container.style.maxHeight = h + "px";
  else
    container.style.maxHeight = (h*3) + "px";

  Object.keys(ids).forEach(function (id) {
    var el = document.getElementById(id);
    el.style.height = (h * ids[id].hmul) + "px";
  });
}
window.onload = function(e) {
  resize();
}
window.onresize = function(e) {
  resize();
}
```

```css
*, *:before, *:after { box-sizing: border-box; }
body { color: black; background: gray; font-size: .1in }

@media screen and (min-width: 501px) {
    body { background: yellow; }
    .flex1 { order:1; width:40%;}
    .flex2 { order:2; width:40%;}
    .flex3 { order:3; width:40%;}
    .flex4 { order:4; width:60%;}
    .flex5 { order:5; width:60%;}
    .flex-container{ flex-wrap:wrap; }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 500px){
    body { background: green; }
    .flex1 { order:1; width:100%;}
    .flex2 { order:3; width:100%;}
    .flex3 { order:4; width:100%;}
    .flex4 { order:2; width:100%;}
    .flex5 { order:5; width:100%;}
    .flex-container{ flex-wrap:nowrap; }
}
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items: center;
  overflow-y:auto;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.flex-item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  background: tomato;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="dimensions"></div>
<div id="container" class="flex-container">
  <div id="flex1" class="flex-item flex1">1</div>
  <div id="flex2" class="flex-item flex2">2</div>
  <div id="flex3" class="flex-item flex3">3</div>
  <div id="flex4" class="flex-item flex4">4</div>
  <div id="flex5" class="flex-item flex5">5</div>
</div>
```